# PKI management with easy-rsa

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, openvpn

I recently setup an OpenVPN server with easy-rsa and have questions about certificate revocation:

In the event that someone's private key gets compromised and I have to revoke the certificate with `revoke-full`, do I need to keep the revoked `.crt/.csr/.key` on the server?

I'm asking because I'm using the certificate owner's full name as the certificate name and was wondering how I would generate a new certificate with the same name if there is already a (revoked) certificate with that name.

Answer (score 1):

No, easy-rsa does not require you to keep revoked certificates around.  The only reason I can come up with to keep them is to have some sort of poor mans audit log.

Just make sure to revoke the certificate before you remove it, because easy-rsa (at least version 2, which I looked at) seems to require the .crt file to be present to revoke a certificate.

Also, if you're still in the process of setting up your pki, consider switching to easy-rsa 3.  That is a complete rewrite, which adds a number of interesting features such as ECDSA support.